# red hat linux yum updates finding old version

Tags: yum

I'm missing something about how yum works with RHEL; when I run "yum update bind-libs", I'm getting a response that it is updating to version 11.11.  When I give it 'y' to proceed it comes back and tells me it can't find it.  Looking on our repo server, I see that we have 11.12 out there.

I don't understand why it isn't seeing/updating to the version we have (11.12) and why it's looking for a version we don't (11.11)?

When I run "yum --enablerepo=* list bind-libs, I get the following output:

bind-libs.x86_64 30:9.3.6-25.P1.e15_11.8    installed

Available Packages

bind-libs.i386   30:9.3.6-25.P1.e15_11.11   rhel5-epel-64

bind-libs.x86_64 30:9.3.6-25.P1.e15_11.11   rhel5-epel-64

I am pointing to my repo via entries in my RHEL.repe and EPEL.repo files on my client machine, in /etc/yum.repos.d/
I have tried both "yum update" and "yum update bind-libs" and gotten the same results (with yum clean all in between of course).

Comment: Do a `yum --enablerepo=* clean all` and then retry.

Comment: I did, thanks for the suggestion.  Still the same issue.  I thought maybe at first that there was a permissions issue, but everything looks correct (owned by root:apache, permissions are 644).

Comment: Post the output of `yum --enablerepo=* list bind-libs` after doing `yum clean all`.

Comment: Well this isn't a network that's connected to the internet, so I can't just d a cut/paste, but essentially it's returning:

Comment: bind-libs.x86_64          30:9.3.6-25.P1.e15_11.8          installed

Available Packages

bind-libs.i386               30:9.3.6-25.P1.e15_11.11        rhel5-epel-64

bind-libs.x86_64          30:9.3.6-25.P1.e15_11.11        rhel5-epel-64

So again, I don't understand where it's seeing that an 11.11 package is available as this doesn't seem to exist on the repo server I'm pointing to.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the above info. Also explain how you are pointing to the new repo ? What command are you running for the update and the resulting output. You don't have to press `y` on `yum install` for this post.

Comment: Done - orginal question modified per request!